# How do I find out which class a member function belongs to

Tags: c++

Suppose I'm defining a new method in a child class:

```
auto ChildClass::newMethod(int foo)
{
    bar(foo);
    // ...
```

I don't know exactly where `bar` comes from, I just know that it's available in the environment of the class (i.e. it's defined in one of its ancestors).

Now, suppose I want to pass `bar` as a callback to an `onBaz` method, which takes a pointer to member function:

```
    // ...
    onBaz(&/* ??? */::bar);
}
```

Without resorting to IDEs, how do I find out which class bar belongs to in this case?

Comment: Personally, I do use an IDE for this.  Most IDE's have a `jump to definition` function which does the job in a single keystroke.

Comment: I have not learned an IDE either.  Within emacs, and with files laid out the way I like, I can grep all files in the build in one grep command searching for "::bar" or perhaps "bar".  On other-peoples-code, I often find more than 2 files with this symbol ... but that is different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I can simply do:

```
    // ...
    onBaz(&ChildClass::bar);
}
```

since `bar` *is available* at `ChildClass`'s environment after all. That will properly evaluate to the pointer to the method in the original class.

To actually *check* which class is that, a trick I like to use is to define a lambda that takes an arbitrary parameter and look at the compilation error:

```
    // ...
    struct Nothing {};
    [](Nothing){}(&ChildClass::bar);
}
```

GCC tells me:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(ChildClass::newMethod()::__lambda0) (void (ActualClassWhereBarIsDefined::*)(int))’
         [](Nothing){}(&ChildClass::bar);
         ^
```

where `ActualClassWhereBarIsDefined` is the class where `bar` is defined.